# Asp MVC section and partial views

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a question regarding ASP sections and partial views.

What ser the benefit of using one over another?

Because if I have a menu, i guest that it could be both as a section, but also as a partial view.

So what is the difference?

Answer (score 6):

A **partial view** is used when you have some view component (optionally with it's own model) that is used in more than one place, or is better separated in to a separate file (for readability, for example).

A **section** is placed in a master page, and allows individual views to populate those areas - they can mandatory or optional. There aren't really pro's and con's in a comparison between the two, since they serve different purposes.

For your menu example, you may have some mark-up that builds a menu (from a collection) which you would want to to use in many places, then a partial view would be the best option.

If you have a single menu on a page, whose contents change based on the page, then you might use a section to require that the view populates the menu (you may use a partial to populate that menu section too).

Comment: So a section is basically an empty container?  Can a section be populated with a partial view?

Comment: Yes, the section acts like a empty container in the master page which can(/should) be populated by the view by any means (including a partial). Whilst they are conceptually an empty container, there is most often some semantics and expected content associated with them (such as the menu).

Answer (score 2):

A partial view works well with Model Binding. You can "type-bind" a partial view so that it will "bind" to the model provided.

```
@Html.Partial("_NavigationMenu", Model.Navigation)
```

A Section is basically like a "placeholder" or "literal" which will just output whatever code is placed within the region in it's appropriate location defined in the "parent".

```
@section JavaScript{
    //some code to be included on the "parent" view 
}
```

Generally, I use sections for various ad-hoc script requirements, or CSS, and partial views for DOM elements like formatting (you could use extensions too) / menus / navigation, etc... same idea as the old ".ascx" controls.

Also:

Partial views do not respect section declarations (by design) and therefor cannot be used.